# using glimpse and structuremap together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, glimpse

I'm adding structuremap to my project for DI/IOC. I built a demo project to get familiar with it before adding it to my application. After getting it working in the demo I started moving it into my app.

I also use glimpse, and that seems to be the only thing causing problems since the structure map addition (so far).

I followed a pretty basic SM tutorial and the NuGet package, and at this point I'm not even injecting any dependencies yet. Just getting everything wired up.

Here's my application_start

```
    IContainer container = new Container(x =>
    {
        x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use<StructureMapControllerActivator>();

    });

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SmDependencyResolver(container));
```

If I disable glimpse, my application works as it did before. I'd be ready to start doing DI. But if I leave glimpse enabled I get a null object exception. Here's the stack trace, I'm not having much luck following it.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Glimpse.Mvc3.Interceptor.ActionInvokerProxyGenerationHook.NonProxyableMemberNotification(Type type, MemberInfo memberInfo)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.MembersCollector.AcceptMethod(MethodInfo method, Boolean onlyVirtuals, IProxyGenerationHook hook)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.ClassMembersCollector.GetMethodToGenerate(MethodInfo method, IProxyGenerationHook hook, Boolean isStandalone)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.MembersCollector.AddMethod(MethodInfo method, IProxyGenerationHook hook, Boolean isStandalone)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.MembersCollector.AddProperty(PropertyInfo property, IProxyGenerationHook hook)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.MembersCollector.CollectProperties(IProxyGenerationHook hook)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.MembersCollector.CollectMembersToProxy(IProxyGenerationHook hook)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.ClassProxyTargetContributor.<CollectElementsToProxyInternal>d__2.MoveNext()
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Contributors.CompositeTypeContributor.CollectElementsToProxy(IProxyGenerationHook hook, MetaType model)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.ClassProxyGenerator.GenerateType(String name, Type[] interfaces, INamingScope namingScope)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.BaseProxyGenerator.ObtainProxyType(CacheKey cacheKey, Func`3 factory)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
at Glimpse.Mvc3.Extensions.ControllerExtentions.TrySetActionInvoker(IController iController, IGlimpseLogger logger)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, ref IController controller, ref IControllerFactory factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2()
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, ref Boolean completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your callstack, it looks like you are using an older version of Glimpse.

This bug was fixed in version 0.85 of Glimpse, available now on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Glimpse/0.85) and [CodePlex](http://glimpse.codeplex.com/). Upgrading should fix your problem.

Comment: I'm on 0.85, what bug are you referring to?

Comment: scratch that. Glimpse.Core was on 0.85 but I forgot to update Glimpse.MVC3. Thanks! Still curious what bug you were talking about, though.

Comment: the error you were getting was the result of a bug in Glimpse.MVC3 0.84. That bug was fixed in Glimpse.MVC3 0.85.